# Trying to pass Generic type as parameter in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, alamofire

I am Using **[AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper)**  i need to make a func that take a Generic parameter like that  :

```
func doSomething < T : BaseMappable > (myCustomClass : T) 
{
    Alamofire.request("url", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: APIKeys().AuthorizedHeader).responseObject(completionHandler: { ( response :DataResponse<T>) in

             let data = response.result.value

            if let array = data?.objects
            {
                for ar in array
                {
                   self.allPromotions.append(ar)
                }
            }

        })


}
```

but iam getting error   :

> **Use of undeclared type 'myCustomClass'**
>   **edit** 
>   as you guys answer me in the comments i put fixed the error but i got another error when iam trying to call this method

i called the method like that

```
doSomething(myCustomClass: Promotions)
```

but i got another error

> Argument type 'Promotions.Type' does not conform to expected type
>   'BaseMappable'

and here's my Promotions class

```
import ObjectMapper


class Promotions : Mappable  {





        var id:Int?
        var workshop_id:Int?
        var title:String?
        var desc:String?
        var start_date:String?
        var expire_date:String?
        var type:String?

        var objects  = [Promotions]()




        required init?(map: Map){

        }

        func mapping(map: Map) {
            id <- map["id"]
            workshop_id <- map["workshop_id"]
            title <- map["title"]
            desc <- map["desc"]
            start_date <- map["start_date"]
            expire_date <- map["expire_date"]
            type <- map["type"]
            objects <- map["promotions"]
        }




}
```

How can i fix that

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: No i didn't ....

Comment: i wrote my answer below. it's used ObjectMapper, not AlamofireObjectMapper. you can refer if you still need this solution.

Answer (score 12):

You need to pass as argument the type of Generic Type T. Try changing

```
myCustomClass : T
```

by

```
myCustomClass : T.Type
```

The result would look like:

**Swift 4:**

```
    func doSomething<T>(myCustomClass : T.Type) where T : BaseMappable
    {
        Alamofire.request("url", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: APIKeys().AuthorizedHeader).responseObject(completionHandler: { ( response :DataResponse<T>) in

                 let data = response.result.value

                if let array = data?.objects
                {
                    for ar in array
                    {
                       self.allPromotions.append(ar)
                    }
                }

            })
    }
```

Then, you should call the method:

```
doSomething(myCustomClass: Promotions.self)
```

Comment: I got this error `Cannot convert value of type '(DataResponse<T>) -> ()' to expected argument type '(DataResponse<Any>) -> Void'`. Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

Just pass the Promotions.self as the parameter.

```
doSomething(myCustomClass: Promotions.self)
```

This'll overcome the error that you are getting in the function call.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution using `Alamofire`, `ObjectMapper` and `PromiseKit`,

- User `Mappable` object.

  ```
  class User: Mappable {

      var id: Int!
      var userName: String!
      var firstName: String?
      var lastName: String?

      required init?(map: Map) {

      }

      // Mappable
      func mapping(map: Map) {
          id                      <- map["id"]
          userName                <- map["userName"]\
          firstName               <- map["firstName"]
          lastName                <- map["lastName"]
      }
  }
  ```
- Class template based function

  ```
  func sendRequest<T: Mappable>(_ url: URLConvertible, method: HTTPMethod = .get, parameters: Parameters? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil, responseObject: T.Type) -> Promise<T> {

      return Promise { resolve, reject in
          Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
              .responseJSON() { response in
                  switch response.result {
                  case .success(let data):
                      let json = JSON(data as Any)
                      let dataObj = json["data"].object
                      let resObj = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: dataObj)
                      resolve(resObj!)
                  case .failure(_):
                      reject(self.generateError(message: nil))
                  }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Usage

**Define in utility class**

```
    func loginWith(userName: String, and password: String) -> Promise<User> {

        let apiPath = "localhost:3000"

        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "email": userName,
            "password": password
        ]

        return sendRequest(apiPath, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, responseObject: User.self)
    }
```

**Use in view controllers**

```
    loginWith(userName: name, and: password)
        .then { response -> Void in
            // response is `User` type object!!!
        }
        .catch { error in
            // show error message
        }
        .always {
            // do something like hide activity indicator
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

myCustomClass is just the name of the input parameter to `doSomething`. The name of the generic type is `T`, so DataResponse should be `DataResponse<T>`.

Comment: it's solved the error but when i called it like that 
`doSomething(myCustomClass:Promotions)`

i got another error 

 **Argument type 'Promotions.Type' does not conform to expected type 'BaseMappable**

Comment: That error is quite straightforward, it says exactly what is wrong... You need to make the class `Promotions` conform to the `Protocol BaseMappable`.

Comment: Promotions is inherit from Mappable and Mappable inherits from BaseMappable

Comment: How do you expect anyone to give you a more detailed answer if you don't even include the piece of code in your question/comment that you are asking about?

Comment: Edited my question