# Pass generic type as function argument in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm attempting to pass a generic argument object type to a class function in Swift. I'm using Swift v5.9.

Here's a minimal example code excerpt:

```
import Foundation

class Test_Class
{
    var Test_Field = 0
    
    init(value)
    {
        self.Test_Field = value
    }
}
```

Which prompts with several errors upon a compile attempt, including:

```
unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'
init(value)

cannot find type 'value' in scope
init(value)

cannot find 'value' in scope
self.Test_Field = value
```

One of the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117301/trying-to-pass-generic-type-as-parameter-in-swift) suggests to use the keyword `T` for every generic argument type, yet attempting to add a `T` for the argument type as such:

```
import Foundation

class Test_Class
{
    var Test_Field = 0
    
    init(value: T)
    {
        self.Test_Field = value
    }
}
```

Results in the following:

```
cannot find type 'T' in scope
init(value: T)
```

They also suggest to put the desired type after the `T` keyword, as in `T.type`, however in this case I don't want to specify a type for `Test_Field`. I want to keep it as a generic.

What is the proper way to pass a generic argument object type to a function in Swift?

Comment: If you look at the sample you posted you'll see `<T>` that is the "declaration"

Comment: Attempting to use `init<T>(value: T.Type)` results in `cannot assign value of type 'T.Type' to type 'Int'`. Do I need to use the `<T>` declaration on the class as well?

Comment: Get rid of the `Type` you have a value.

Comment: Can you describe the class you are trying to write? What does it do? What is `Test_Field` supposed to be? You assigned it `0`, so it should be an `Int`, not generic at all.

Comment: @loremipsum still the same error if I remove the `Type`.

Comment: @Sweeper well, in this case I needed to assign some value to the generic, otherwise I get a `type annotation missing in pattern` error, and with the `?` I get a `consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'`. I also tried setting it to `nil`, but then I get a `'nil' requires a contextual type` error. The purpose of setting it to 0 initially is so those errors don't occur.

Comment: @Runsva May I suggest that you read the [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics) chapter of the Swift book. I think you will find it very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics) chapter of the Swift book will be very helpful for your question.

From reading that you will find that the likely answer to your question is as follows:

```swift
class TestClass<T> {
    var testField: T

    init(value: T) {
        self.testField = value
    }
}

let someTest = TestClass(value: "Hello") // with a String
print(someTest.testField)
let otherTest = TestClass(value: 42) // with an Int
print(otherTest.testField)
```

As you can see from the samples below the class, you can create instances of `TestClass` with any type of value.

But note that once you create an instance for a given type of value, you can't assign a value of a different type to that instance.

For example, once you do:

```
let someTest = TestClass(value: "Hello") // with a String
```

you can do:

```
someTest.testField = "Goodbye" // this is OK
```

but you can't do:

```
someTest.testField = 42 // this won't compile
```

The last line won't work because the `someTest` instance was created for `String` so `testField`'s type is `String`. So you can't assign it a value of type `Int`.